Ubuntu Studio 24.04 Audio Lagging behind video in Cheese
I recently installed Ubuntu Studio 24.04. Today I tried to use Cheese but the audio was lagging behind the video in the recorded video. I did not have this problem in 22.04 with the exact same laptop. Any advice appreciated.

Can you try installing cheese via apt instead of snap? Use the commands sudo snap remove cheese and sudo apt install cheese

Yeah, I tried that but to no avail. I noticed that there were quite a few errors when I ran cheese from the terminal. I tore my hair out with this for 4 hours and then just went back to 22.04 because cheese runs fine with that and I really needed to use it witthout having to spend weeks on figuring it out on 24.04. I think it might have something to do with pipewire audio. I was using Ubuntu Studio 24.04

24.10 will be released in a week. Can you test it and let us know if it works there? The information may help future users

Yes, very gladly. I will let you know how it works. Thanks.

Hello. I just installed Ubuntu Studio 24.10 Limited Release and Cheese works fine on that. No error messages when installing from terminal.

Glad to know that it was some sort of single release bug that has been resolved
